# How do I get Blender to save Specular and other settings when exporting FBXes?

Tags: materials, export, .fbx

I have been working on a set of models that I want to export as FBX.  The default Specular setting seems to be 0.5, which gives a fake, plastic look to the models.  Normally I set the specular to 0.1, but when I export the FBX, Blender always resets the setting to 0.5.  How do I get Blender to retain my settings when I export?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Not quite.  The diffuse and normal textures stay attached, but the texture that's plugged into the alpha channel doesn't, and it resets Metallic, Specular, and Roughness.  I've tested this by exporting an FBX and re-importing it back into Blender.  Not sure why Blender won't save the figure exactly as it is.